# How to make DocumentationTools palette useable?

Tags: workbench, palettes

I am writing the documentation for my package using Wolfram Workbench 2.  But when I open DocumentationTools under Palettes, I get this unpolished piece of junk:

[image]

The top half is a total waste of space (it appears to be some kind of warning...), and the right-half of all the buttons are cut off by the completely fixed size of the window.  **Option Inspector** refuses to respond to any changes made for Window Properties for "DocumentationTools".

What can I do to make this more useable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can press the blue `Enable Dynamics` button to make the warning disappear.

(You also appear to have a zoom problem that I can't replicate, perhaps [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44174/5485) is relevant?)

Here are screenies before and after pressing the button:

[image][image]